# Wireless mayhem with Linux

Tags: wireless-networking, linux-mint

The wireless connection I had setup was working absolutely fine earlier.

I then plugged it to another router to configure via a network cable and whilst it allowed me to access the router details, I wasn't able to browse the Internet. My understanding is whilst I have another device connected via cable, it is given preference over the wireless network.

I then unplugged the router and expected to have the wireless connection up and running again. Nada. Zilch. I restart the device and still no luck. I deleted the wireless connection details via network manager and restarted hoping to clear any details.

Once it restarted, I re-configured the wireless settings and still nothing. I can connect to the wireless network via other PCs. The only message I get is unable to connect. The connection details are correct. I am running a Debian derivative of Linux i.e. Linux Mint version 12. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Good news. I am back online. The problem seems to be the router I was configuring which also supports wireless connectivity and it has the same SSID as the router currently plugged into the modem. I simply disconnected the router I was configuring and voilà.

Question: Why are all the other computers working fine and the only device that had an issue was my laptop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was just luck.  If there are multiple same ssids on a network, then each device will connect to whichever one it likes, whichever one it sees first, or responds first.

It will also stay connected to the SSID unless it goes out of range (or has some other criteria for changing).  So they were all happily connected, the second duplicate ssid was introduced, and the new device connected to it, rather than the proper one.

Comment: Thanks. Does it not matter that the router had another subnet defined? For example, the wireless network is on the 192.168.1.x subnet whilst the new router I was attempting to configure was setup to use the 192.168.0.x.

Comment: No, IP addressing has no bearing on wifi connectivity, just as IP has no bearing on how successfully a cable is plugged into a switch.  It operates at a lower level.  This answer is presuming that "unable to connect" was referring to the wifi connectivity, not some other connectivity.